# Number of heads in 100 Coin toss

Tags: probability, self-study, statistical-significance, inference, expected-value

I got a coin that follows a certain distribution (with the probability of head).

I toss the coins 100 times. What is the correlation between:

1. number of heads I got (in the 100 toss).
2. number of heads I got in the first 10 toss.

Comment: Could you clarify the sense in which the probability of head "follows a Normal distribution"?  Which Normal distribution?  And do you want a correlation that is conditional on the coin or do you want an unconditional answer?  Do you mean "correlation" in the sense of a correlation coefficient or in some generic sense (and if it's the latter, what sense exactly)?

Comment: Thanks for the comment, fixed. Got it.

Comment: @NygenPatricia you have only edited the question slightly. Regarding the distribution, did you mean a coin whose flips are independent and follow a Bernoulli distribution (probability p for heads and probability p for tails)? Regarding the type of correlation, could you clarify this.